# Fetch data from Microsoft Project online to Postman(Or any other software used to make rest calls)

Tags: rest, azure, sharepoint, postman, project-server

I want to fetch the data from Microsoft Project Online to Postman (Or any other similar software like postman which are used to make rest calls).

When I used **Postman** **interceptor** add on for chrome I was able to get the data. But when I tried to pass headers manually then I wasn't able to get it.

May I know how I can get the data in Postman or similar software.

Thanks

Comment: Should this have the dynamics-crm tag?

Comment: I did not find any option for Project online, so I added the relevant tags that  I thought were right.